# How to display SQL results as columns and group them by a column in DB2?

Tags: sql, group-by, db2, pivot-table

Let's say I have two tables, TABLE_A and TABLE_B defined as follows:

### TABLE_A

```
    NAME   OTHER_COLUMN
    A05    OTHER_VALUE
    A06    OTHER_VALUE
    A08    OTHER_VALUE
```

### TABLE_B

```
    NAME    CODE     ATTRIBUTE
    A05     01       A05_01-A
    A05     01       A05_01-B
    A05     02       A05_02-A
    A05     03       A05_03-A
    A05     04       A05_04-A
    
    A06     01       A06_01-A
    A06     02       A06_02-A
    A06     04       A06_04-A
    A06     04       A06_04-B
    A06     04       A06_04-C
    A06     04       A06_04-D
    A06     05       A06_05-A
    
    A08     01       A08_01-A
    A08     02       A08_02-A
    A08     02       A08_02-B
```

What I need to do is a query to display the results of distinct **CODES** as columns with the **ATTRIBUTES** associated per **NAME**.

In a graphical way, I am expecting something like this:

```
    NAME    OTHER_COLUMN    CODE_01     CODE_02     CODE_03     CODE_04     CODE_05
    A05     OTHER_VALUE     A05_01-A    A05_02-A    A05_03-A    A05_04-A    NULL
    A05     OTHER_VALUE     A05_01-B    A05_02-A    A05_03-A    A05_04-A    NULL
    A06     OTHER_VALUE     A06_01-A    A06_02-A    NULL        A06_04-A    A06_05-A
    A06     OTHER_VALUE     A06_01-A    A06_02-A    NULL        A06_04-B    A06_05-A
    A06     OTHER_VALUE     A06_01-A    A06_02-A    NULL        A06_04-C    A06_05-A
    A06     OTHER_VALUE     A06_01-A    A06_02-A    NULL        A06_04-D    A06_05-A
    A08     OTHER_VALUE     A08_01-A    A08_02-A    NULL        NULL        NULL
    A08     OTHER_VALUE     A08_01-A    A08_02-B    NULL        NULL        NULL
```

I found that in order to accomplish that I need to do a PIVOT table. In DB2 it is possible using the function DECODE() that is similar to use CASE.

So, here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    A.NAME, A.OTHER_COLUMN,
    DECODE(B.CODE, '01', B.ATTRIBUTE) AS CODE_01,
    DECODE(B.CODE, '02', B.ATTRIBUTE) AS CODE_02,
    DECODE(B.CODE, '03', B.ATTRIBUTE) AS CODE_03,
    DECODE(B.CODE, '04', B.ATTRIBUTE) AS CODE_04,
    DECODE(B.CODE, '05', B.ATTRIBUTE) AS CODE_05
FROM TABLE_A A
INNER JOIN TABLE_B B
    ON A.NAME = B.NAME
```

I would use the **GROUP BY A.NAME, A.OTHER_COLUMN** statement at the end of the query, however if I do that, I would get one row per NAME value without considering if I have more than one ATTRIBUTE per CODE. In that case, my result is this:

```
    NAME    OTHER_COLUMN    CODE_01     CODE_02     CODE_03     CODE_04     CODE_05
    A05     OTHER_VALUE     A05_01-A    A05_02-A    A05_03-A    A05_04-A    NULL
    A06     OTHER_VALUE     A06_01-A    A06_02-A    NULL        A06_04-A    A06_05-A
    A08     OTHER_VALUE     A08_01-A    A08_02-A    NULL        NULL        NULL
```

I hope you wise people can help me to find out what I'm missing here.

Comment: How would you want to handle multiple duplicates, for example an additional `A05     02       A05_02-B` in your Table_B

Comment: By the way, this is quite a well-formed first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little hard to decipher the question in your question.  But, you seem to want multiple columns for each name, one for each code (if present).

If so, use `row_number()` to enumerate them and then include that in the aggregation:

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.OTHER_COLUMN,
       MAX(CASE B.CODE WHEN '01' THEN B.ATTRIBUTE END) AS CODE_01,
       MAX(CASE B.CODE WHEN '02' THEN B.ATTRIBUTE END) AS CODE_02,
       MAX(CASE B.CODE WHEN '03' THEN B.ATTRIBUTE END) AS CODE_03,
       MAX(CASE B.CODE WHEN '04' THEN B.ATTRIBUTE END) AS CODE_04,
       MAX(CASE B.CODE WHEN '05' THEN B.ATTRIBUTE END) AS CODE_05
FROM TABLE_A A INNER JOIN
     (SELECT B.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.NAME, B.CODE ORDER BY B.ATTRIBUTE) as seqnum
      FROM TABLE_B B
     ) B
     ON A.NAME = B.NAME
GROUP BY A.NAME, A.OTHER_COLUMN, seqnum;
```

If you desired, you could include `seqnum` in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Is the `END` inside the partition clause a DB2'ism? Never seen that syntax before.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson . . . No it isn't.  Thank you.

Comment: That's exactly the solution I need! Thanks a lot :)